# HTML & CSS - Showing and Hiding a div

Tags: jquery, css, html, show-hide

I have a div with id 'toggle'. I want to simply have a link or button that when pressed will display the div, and then when clicked again hide the div. I would preferably like it animated as with jQuery though I can't seem to get jQuery working though I'm probably making mistakes. So how can I do this? :)

Answer (score 8):

```
 $('#youAnchorId').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault():
    $('#toggle').toggle(); //use .fadeToggle() if you want fade animation.
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5rCc/2/).

Here's the JS:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#redBox').fadeToggle();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#toggleDiv').on('click', function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#toggle').fadeToggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

​
[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GmUHE/)